# Копирование строк таблицы mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

Как скопировать одну строку таблицы в эту же таблицу?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11331573/mysql-copy-row-but-with-new-id первый ответ должен вам помочь

Comment: @AntonKucenko но нужно в одном столбце поменять значения.

Comment: @ВладиславСамохин Этого не было написано в исходном тексте вопроса. На будущее рекомендую формулировать вопрос более чётко.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужен [insert-select](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html), например:

```
insert into t1(a, b, c)
select aa as a, bb as b, 123 as c
from t2
```

Поля скопируются из `aa` в `a`, `bb` в `b`, а просто число `123` в поле `c`.

Comment: мне кажется, что алиасы тут не нужны, поля вставляются не по именам а по порядку.